# Is there any function in Arduino to access the last element of an array

Tags: c, json, arduino

I am writing a program where I need to access the last element of the array from a json document. array is initially empty and size is not defined. is there a way to get the last element like in python we use a[-1] to access the last.

```
JsonArray Time_hours = doc["Time"]["hours"];
JsonArray Time_min = doc["Time"]["min"];

int size_hours = sizeof(Time_hours) / sizeof(int);
int size_min = sizeof(Time_min) / sizeof(int);

for(int i=1;i< size_hours ;i++){

  if(now.hour() == Time_hours[i] && now.minute() == Time_min[i])
  {
    ring_bell(1);
  }
 }
```

Comment: You need to know the size. It would help to see an example of what you're working with.

Comment: What are you using to parse the json document?

Comment: i am using Arduinojson library to parse the json formate.

Comment: Arduino code is C++, and `JsonArray` is a class. So it will have a method that tells you the length of the array. You can google `Arduino JsonArray length` to find the name of that method.

Comment: `Time_hours.size()`

Answer (score 2):

As ninja said, you need to know the size, once you know the size you know do something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define len(arr) sizeof (arr)/sizeof (arr[0])

int main()
{
    int a[5] = {2,5,6,1,4};
    printf("%zu\n",len(a));
    printf("%d\n",a[len(a) - 1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof` is an operator, not a function; you don't need the parentheses.

Comment: It is more readable like this, at least for me, is it bad practice?

Comment: Well, you may put parentheses where you want. I perceive unnecessary parentheses as clutter. It's always a matter of style to add them when not necessary, arguing leads to "style wars", similar with placement of braces or [Yoda Conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions). At least I would separate the keyword from the opening parenthesis to make it clear that it is not a function.

Comment: I guess OP has a JSON array representation, not a simple C array

Comment: i want to take the variable from a json array,place it in a C array and want to iterate through it using for loop.but to place a limit i need to know the size of the array which is not given . so how should i proceed

Comment: I tried the sizeof  function but it does not return the correct number. in my case it returned 2 for an array of 8 elements

Comment: Looks like you are using a pointer. You have to either define your array as int name[size] to have a fix size or to use malloc for allocate as much memory you need. For JSON array size I think you can use arrayName.size() to get the size if I remember correctly, better check the documentation to see the name of the function.

Comment: `Time_hours.size()`